# If not in JSON [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
 {"id":"1001","token":"12345678987654","name":"Name 1"},
 {"id":"1010","token":"876543245643","name":"Name 2"}
]
```

I can print the numbers that exist in JSON as follows.

```
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    // same codes
}
```

However, if there is no 1234 number in JSON, I want the DIV element to appear. DIV element normally not visible

```
var number = 1234;
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].id !== number) {
            document.getElementById('addBox').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

If there is no 1234 in JSON, I want it to appear. It does not need to appear for those who exist.

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/ugyk6x98/)

Comment: so..where's the problem?

Comment: `users[i].id` may not an integer. So try `if (+users[i].id !== 1234)`.

Comment: Hi @Manav , the number `1234` does not exist in JSON. So, I want the DIV element to appear. But in my code, it doesn't show up for `1234`. The DIV element appears for other numbers. If you wish, you can see the console in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Manav So, display DIV element only if Number `1234` is not available in the JSON

Comment: You need to check all the users before making final determination if a specific one exists or not

Comment: Welcome!
The way you use it, it will show `addBox` even for one user who's `id` isn't `1234` (assuming you've change to compare strings or numbers) , and the only way it will not show that box is if no users exist or all of them have `id` equal to `1234`.
See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var users1=[
 {"id":"1001","token":"12345678987654","name":"Name 1"},
 {"id":"1010","token":"876543245643","name":"Name 2"}
];

var users2=[
 {"id":"1001","token":"12345678987654","name":"Name 1"},
 {"id":"1010","token":"876543245643","name":"Name 2"},
 {"id":"1234","token":"4876543245643","name":"Name 4"}
];

var number=1234;

console.log("number in users1 (number to string): "+
  users1.some(user=>user.id==""+number)
);
console.log("number in users2 (number to string): "+
  users2.some(user=>user.id==""+number)
);
console.log("number in users1 (string to number): "+
  users1.some(user=>+user.id==number)
);
console.log("number in users2 (string to number): "+
  users2.some(user=>+user.id==number)
);
```

So, for your case:

```
var number = 1234;
if(!users.some(user=>user.id==""+number))
  document.getElementById('addBox').style.display = 'block';
```

or:

```
var number = 1234;
if(!users.some(user=>+user.id==number))
  document.getElementById('addBox').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your interest but my question is the number 1234 does not exist in `users1`. It should then point to the `addBox` element. So if there is no 1234 in JSON, "addBox" should appear.

Comment: @Emre7, my bad, fixed: added `!` (not).
Let me know if it works for you now.
If it does: select and up-vote?!? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried but I can't. I need a minimum of 15 points, and I have 13 points.

Comment: @Emre7, as I've said... :)
Hope you remember me when you get there - very soon!

Answer (score 2):

You're using strict not equal (`!==`) between a string and a number:

```js
const id = "1001";
console.log(id !== 1001);
console.log(id !== "1001");
```

The above should demonstrate the problem to you.